# Loading a time series dataframe with multiple headers - Melting it down

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe below which I originally loaded as:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Rectifier_DB.xlsx", header = [0,1], index_col=0)
```

|  | 1/1/2015 | 1/1/2015 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2015 | 3/1/2015 | 3/1/2015 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rectifier | Volts | Amps | Volts | Amps | Volts | Amps |
| 9E220ECP5001 | 11.10 | 31.95 |  |  | 11.30 | 31.05 |
| 9E220ECP5002 | 19.30 | 62.60 |  |  | 13.10 | 39.60 |
| 9E220ECP5003 | 4.50 | 6.30 |  |  | 4.60 | 6.30 |

I had a lot of trouble attempting to plot this data, Amps vs time or Volts vs time.

Is there a way I can either plot this dataframe as is or maybe convert into a simpler format such as below?

| Rectifier | Date | Volts | Amps |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9E220ECP5001 | 1/1/2015 | 11.10 | 31.95 |  |  |  |
| 9E220ECP5001 | 2/1/2015 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9E220ECP5001 | 3/1/2015 | 11.30 | 31.05 |  |  |  |
| 9E220ECP5002 | 1/1/2015 | 19.30 | 62.60 |  |  |  |
| 9E220ECP5002 | 2/1/2015 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9E220ECP5002 | 3/1/2015 | 13.10 | 39.60 |  |  |  |
| 9E220ECP5003 | 1/1/2015 | 4.50 | 6.30 |  |  |  |
| 9E220ECP5003 | 2/1/2015 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9E220ECP5003 | 3/1/2015 | 4.60 | 6.30 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get some help with this, the answer is below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Rectifier_DB.xlsx", 
                 header=[0,1],
                 index_col=0)

df = (df.stack(level=0, dropna=False)
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .rename({'level_1': 'Date'}, axis=1))
```